# A global lightning component that's write once, reusable on service cloud, sales cloud and communities

Tags: lightning-web-components

Can one create a lightning component (e.g. a custom search UI) that is omnipresent and can be re-used in several contexts: within the service cloud, sales cloud, communities cloud, visualforce pages? Within these contexts, can it also be available agnostic to the object and records context?

Is such re-usability in terms of the component placement even possible, given that these are very different contexts? What design considerations should be kept to create such a component? Pointers/links for either case would be appreciated.

Comment: taking it a step back, do you have something written already and are asking about how to make it reusable? Or are you asking specifically about doing some sort of custom search UI? I'd [edit] your question with any example code you may have already as that would help answer

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I haven't written anything already. I'm considering the design implications as I'm grokking the SalesForce dev ecosystem. If my question isn't hitting it on the nail, what's a good resource for me to dive deeper into this topic?

Comment: I'm not sure what design implications you're considering. By mentioning Service and Sales console, I assume you're referring to what objects you should be searching? Have you looked at the out of the box global search bar in Salesforce, is there some limitation that is pushing you towards custom?